# Using json mappers to retrieve and save data with firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use json mappers to handle my Flutter Firebase Firestore serialization and deserialization. Right now I'm using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package, which has gotten me past most hurdles.

I'm seeing an issue when inserting / updating though. I have to be able to get my dart object into the json `Map` form, not the `String` form to properly insert it. While the library provides a `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => ...` function implementation, this function doesn't convert nested objects, which basically makes it worthless.

To work around this I'm converting the json into a `String`, then back into a `Map` doing the following:

```dart
    final json = jsonEncode(reg);
    final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);
```

**This is obviously bad. How can I get my dart object into a json `Map` form better?**

I'm also having to do weird things, like grab the snapshot data, and grab the document id, and then insert the id into the data map before deserializing it, so I have the id in the data model, and then remove it before serializing. **There has to be a better way to auto-serialize and deserialize from firebase. What am I missing?**

```dart
    final snapshot = document.data;
    snapshot['id'] = documentID;
```

Comment: query snapshot listener should give you the snapshot data as a json object. Can you show how you are fetching the data? change.doc should give you a nested json object as far as i know.

Comment: I'm doing this: `_firestore.collection("organizations/${org.id}/registrations").snapshots().listen`

So yes this gives the data as a json map, however many deserialization libs have a problem with this because it returns a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` for nested json objects, not a `Map<String, dynamic>`. json_serializable library works around this with an option in the `build.yaml`. My problem isn't with reading right now, but writing. json_serializable can't easily get the updated object back into a `Map<String, dynamic>` json form that I can find, which is what firebase wants.

Comment: Ok, will get back if I find a better way. Thanks